# rich:listShuttle formatting

Tags: java, css, jsf, richfaces

Whenever the number of items in my source list is more than 17, the list formatting goes wrong, it produces an empty space on top of the list. Scroll bar is always present, when I move out an item from source list to target list, making the count 17 or less in source list, the formatting is fine. Is there a work around to control formatting. Below  are the images: unformatted(more than 17 items) and formatted(less than 18 items.)

[image]
[image]

```
<div class="add-company-input-section">

        <h:panelGrid id="ModalPanel" columns="2" columnClasses="rc,lc">


            <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:5px">Name: </label>
            <h:inputText id="companyName"  value="#{companyAdminAction.companyName}"/>

            <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-top:5px">Website: </label>
            <h:inputText id="websiteName"  value="#{companyAdminAction.website}"/>

            <br/>

        </h:panelGrid>

                    <h3 style="color:#C88039; padding-bottom:5px;">Jurisdictions: </h3>
            <rich:listShuttle id="companyJurisdictionShutle"
                              sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.statesList}"
                              targetValue="#{companyAdminAction.selectedStates}"
                              var="item" orderControlsVisible="false" fastOrderControlsVisible="false"
                              sourceCaptionLabel="Available"
                              targetCaptionLabel="Selected">
                <rich:column>
                    #{item}
                </rich:column>
            </rich:listShuttle>


    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried to submit this on richfaces forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a css dependency, adding a style class to my listshuttle fixed it.

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .lishShuttle td{vertical-align:top;}
   </style>

      <rich:listShuttle id="companyJurisdictionShutle"
                                  sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.jurisdictionList}"
                                  targetValue="#{companyAdminAction.targetJurisdictionList}"
                                  converter="#{dmpJurisdictionConverter}"
                                  rowKeyConverter="dmpJurisdictionConverter"
                                  rowClasses=""
                                  var="item" orderControlsVisible="false" fastOrderControlsVisible="false"
                                  sourceCaptionLabel="Available"
                                  targetCaptionLabel="Selected" styleClass="lishShuttle">
                    <rich:column>
                        #{item}
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:listShuttle>
```